# USB OTG only working on charging mode

Tags: adb, 4.4-kitkat, charging, usb-on-the-go

I have an android tablet that came with OTG support and adb binary already installed, I would like to connect my phone to use adb but when I connect it only charges the phone and adb does not show my device connected, the default usb setting of my phone is MTP, my tablet seems not have a setting to change the usb mode.

Comment: Have you activated USB debugging on the tablet?

Comment: yes I did on both

Comment: Did You try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.htetznaing.adbotg

Comment: Yes and not worked, neither Bugjaeguer. I'm not sure but I think its about a property called ro.sys.usb.charging.only that is set true, idk what this property is for, if you know let me know, anyway I'll try later set ro.sys.usb.charging.only=false and see whats happen